# centering overflowed content

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamically created list of `<a>` tags (without text) to which I apply a background image. I display these icons within `<div>` container using the `float: left;` style.

When the row of icons becomes too long it overflows and begins a new row as expected.

How can I either center this last row, or spread the icons out evenly across the row?

Comment: Some code you've tried?

Comment: how were you able to set the background image without setting width/height to the <a> tag ?

Comment: I need to see your code, i really do

Comment: @AdityaSaxena `<a href="" style="background: url('/images/flags/cy.png'); background-size: 100%; width: 34px; height: 34px"></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool..so for **centering the row**, this is what you need : http://jsbin.com/uPeYaJE/1/edit

Screencapture:

[image]

CSS:

```
.container{
  width:200px;
  background-color:#666666;
  overflow:auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.container a{
  display:inline-block;
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/34/34'); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%; 
  width: 34px; 
  height: 34px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. I was going the `<ul>` way but this makes it a lot easier.

Comment: <ul> is semantically correct, though - because this is a list of icons. This solution just replicates what you'd have in your current setup.

Comment: The problem I was having with `<ul>` is that it would center the first row but as soon as it wraps around everything would be left aligned.

Comment: again, you can use text-align center on the <ul> and display:inline-block; on the <li>'s